# Check database connection before open a new one

Tags: perl, dbi, mojolicious

I'm having a mojolicious app structured like this:

```
 /root_dir/lib/Mojo_App/Controller/Main.pm  
 /root_dir/lib/Mojo_App/Database/Db.pm  
 /root_dir/ ...
```

In Database::Db I have a subroutine that creates a connection to SQL SERVER. That subroutine gets exported and used in Main.pm
Example:
Database::DB

```
my $config = {
db1 => {
    host => 'dbi:Driver:server=ip01;database=db01',
    user => 'user01',
    pass => 'pass01'
},
db2 => {
    host => 'dbi:Driver:server=ip02;database=db02',
    user => 'user02',
    pass => 'pass02'
},
db3 => {
    host => 'dbi:Driver:server=ip03;database=db03',
    user => 'user03',
    pass => 'pass03'
}
};


sub connect_db {
use DBI;
my $self = shift;

return 0 unless $self;

my $dbh;

if (exists($config->{$self})) { 
    return $dbh = DBI->connect($config->{$self}->{host}, $config->{$self}->{user}, $config->{$self}->{pass}) || die( $DBI::errstr . "\n" ) ;
} else {
    return "Connection not in config. \n" ;
}
return $dbh; 

}
```

In Main.pm I am connecting like this:

```
my $dbh = connect_db('db1');
```

Now lets say I need to connect to the database on the index page, so I will have in Main.pm a subroutine index like this:

```
sub index {
    my $self = shift;
    my $dbh = connect_db('db1');
    ...
    $self->render();
}
```

Now I dont want that everytime a user accesses the index page a new connection to be made,I want to check if a connection is alive and if not create it.
I have read about ping method, but I dont know how I can implement it here.
Also I have read about DBIx and tried the following implementation:

```
sub connect_db {
use DBIx::Connector;

my $self = shift;

return 0 unless $self;

my $dbh;

if (exists($config->{$self})) { 
    my $conn = DBIx::Connector->new($config->{$self}->{host}, $config->{$self}->{user}, $config->{$self}->{pass}, {
        RaiseError => 1,
        AutoCommit => 1,
    });
    return $dbh = $conn->dbh; ;
} else {
    return "Connection not in config. \n" ;
}
return $dbh; 
}
```

Would this implementation achieve what I want? When a database connection is active to be used and not recreated. If yes, is it safe to use DBIx like Dbi? I am referring here to:

```
my $dbh  = $conn->dbh;
$dbh->do('INSERT INTO foo (name) VALUES (?)', undef, 'Fred' );
and not 
$conn->run(fixup => sub {
$_->do('INSERT INTO foo (name) VALUES (?)', undef, 'Fred' );
});
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is safe to use the `dbh` method from a DBIx::Connector object and then use that as a normal DBI handle, but you miss out on most of the benefits of DBIx::Connector if you don't keep the DBIx::Connector object around. Creating a new DBIx::Connector object will mean that a new connection is required, as that object is where connections are cached. In addition, whenever you call `->dbh` or `->run` is when DBIx::Connector checks that the connection is active and that you haven't forked, and makes a new connection if needed. Thus it is better to store and pass around the DBIx::Connector object, and then have any individual segment of code retrieve a `dbh` or call `run`. In a Mojolicious application it's common to store something like this in an application [helper](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojolicious::Guides::Tutorial#Helpers) (but of course you can put it wherever is convenient).

```
# in application startup
my %dbs;
$app->helper(db => sub {
  my ($c, $name) = @_;
  return $dbs{$name} //= DBIx::Connector->new(...);
});

# elsewhere
my $dbh = $c->db('db1')->dbh;
# or
$c->db('db1')->run(...);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, just to be sure I understand. If I have this
     sub connect_db {
      .. same as above until ...
     my $conn = DBIx::Connector->new(...);
     return $conn ;
      ... 
}
And in my controller I use my $conn = connect_db('db1'); my $dbh = $conn->dbh(); Would I achieve what I'm trying to do? Thank you

Comment: No, that would still create a new DBIx::Connector object and thus require reconnecting every time you call connect_db.

Comment: So the correct way is to create a helper as you showed and in controller use $dbh = $c->db->dbh?

Comment: Yes, or store your DBIx::Connector object some other way. The important part is that you want to always keep the same DBIx::Connector object around for every request to use.

Comment: Im having trouble setting that up, I have added my attempt on this paste bin link 
https://pastebin.com/2CqugMrz 
because I can't format here in comments... Can you please take a look and post the answer if its correct?

Comment: @rooger Three problems: 1. The first parameter a helper receives is the controller object, not the string you passed in. 2. You pass an argument to the helper as `$c->db('db1')` not `$c->db->('db1')`. 3. Since you want to keep multiple database connections, you need multiple DBIx::Connector objects, so you should store them in a hash instead of a scalar variable, with the strings you pass in as keys.

Comment: I updated the example to use a hash with named connectors.

Comment: I have made the necessary changes and it works! But just to take one final check up if I did it right, can you please take a look?
https://pastebin.com/5vg0TcBt
Thank you

Comment: You are still making a new DBIx::Connector object every time you call the helper. That's why I used the `//=` operator, so that it only creates and assigns a new DBIx::Connector object if that key does not have a defined value (i.e. does not have a DBIx::Connector object yet). Your error handling should probably [die](https://perldoc.pl/functions/die) instead of returning a string that won't work.

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem that [`DBI::connect_cached`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#connect_cached) is supposed to solve:

> ```
> $dbh = DBI->connect_cached($data_source, $username, $password)
>       or die $DBI::errstr;
> $dbh = DBI->connect_cached($data_source, $username, $password, \%attr)
>       or die $DBI::errstr;
> ```
>
> `connect_cached` is like "`connect`", except that the database handle returned is also stored in a hash associated with the given parameters. If another call is made to `connect_cached` with the same parameter values, then the corresponding cached `$dbh` will be returned if it is still valid. The cached database handle is replaced with a new connection if it has been disconnected or if the `ping` method fails.

See the docs for important disclaimers.

Comment: Thanks reply,I have read this before posting but decided its not the best solution for my app because I have connection to 3 different dbs/ip's and in the docs for connect_cached says:
Caching connections can be useful in some applications, but it can also cause problems, such as too many connections, and so should be used with care. In particular, avoid changing the attributes of a database handle created via connect_cached() because it will affect other code that may be using the same handle. When connect_cached() returns a handle the attributes will be reset to their initial values.

Comment: I don't see the comment you quoted, @rooger, to be speaking to any reason why you could not use connect_cached.  The three different databases would be using three different caches. And the 'too many connections' issue would not be made worse by using connect_cached than it would be by using DBIx::Connector.  Seems safe to me unless you're actually mutating the handles after connection.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, So by using connect_cache like 
(return $dbh = DBI->connect_cached(...) in my connect_db sub)  if a user on index refreshes the page 50 times, there would be only 1 connection made?
Is there a way to check how many connection are made to SQL Server? Also, would there be  a way to implement ping? I was thinking something like  return $dbh = DBI->connect(...) unless $dbh->ping(); but this would make the connection anyway before ping is made...

Comment: LE: after some reading on the internet, more and more people say that DBIx::Connector is better than connect_cached
https://justatheory.com/tags/dbixconnector/
https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Connector - quote "You might be familiar with ... and with the DBI's connect_cached() constructor. DBIx::Connector serves a similar need, but does a much better job."
 https://www.reddit.com/r/perl/comments/54nl6c/dbi_connection_pooling_under_fcgifastcgi/ - "That aside, it's recommended to use a connection manager like DBIx::Connector rather than relying on connect_cached ".

Comment: What are your opinions? For me the only downside of dbix connector is that it has been last updated in 2016

Comment: Yes, DBIx::Connector is a better option. It does not need to be updated often since it just delegates to DBI.